# Oracle Migration Workbench

Tags: oracle, migration, db2, udb

Does anybody know anything about using Migration Workbench to migrate db2 database to oracle 10G? I am getting a strange SQL1402N error when I try to get source capture.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is some kind of problem with the user you are trying to connect with.

According to the message reference for [SQL1402N](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql1402.htm):

> SQL1402N
>   Unable to authenticate user due to unexpected system error.
>   Explanation:
>
> Call your system administrator. On unix-based systems, the file db2ckpw may not have the correct permission bits set, or the system may have run out of swap/paging space. On Windows NT, the DB2 security service may not have been started or the account may be locked.
>
> The command can not be processed.
>
> Federated system users: this situation can also be detected by the data source.
>   User response:
>
> On unix-based systems, have the system administrator ensure the correct access permissions are set for db2ckpw, and that there is enough swap/paging space allocated. On Windows NT, have the system administrator verify that the DB2 security service is installed and started. If the service is running then ensure that the account is not locked.